# How to use formControl with mat-stepper and ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-material

How I can put a `formControlName` for each input inside of the stepper,
when the second input has the error appears in the previous step.

**HTML**

```
   <mat-vertical-stepper  #stepper [linear]="true">
        <mat-step  [stepControl]="fFormGroup" label="{{bloq.bloq.name}}" *ngFor="let bloq of bloqAuditory;let i = index">
             <form [formGroup]="fFormGroup">
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-5">
                          <mat-form-field>
                              <input matInput placeholder="Nombre" formControlName="nameCtrl" >
                          </mat-form-field>    
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
          </mat-step>
    </mat-vertical-stepper>
```

**TS**

```
this.fFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
  nameCtrl : ['',Validators.required]
})
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, please try to explain in more detail which behaviour or error you're getting and what is the expected behaviour. Also, putting together a stackblitz may help to get answers.

Comment: I am learning angular, but still able to understand the question. Angular examples use -  <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup"  ,.... <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup" . But what if you create using an ngFor and on mat-step , what to use for [stepControl]. you can not hardcode like first second etc.Strange that there are no answers.